# How to fix unaligned pointer (char**)

Tags: c++, macos, pointers, alignment

Clang 3.3 UBSan (undefined behavior sanitizer) flagged the following code for unaligned access:

```
Address.cc:545:27: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x60c00000a7df for type 'char *', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x60c00000a7df: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00 ef  a7 00 00 c0 60 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c0  a8 64 0c 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00
             ^
Address.cc:547:19: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0x60c00000a7ef for type 'const struct in_addr', which requires 4 byte alignment
0x60c00000a7ef: note: pointer points here
 00 00 00 00 c0  a8 64 0c 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00
             ^
```

The code in question is shown below (ignore the incorrect return type for `operator=`):

```
bool
Ip::Address::operator =(const struct hostent &s)
{
    struct in_addr* ipv4 = NULL;

    switch (s.h_addrtype) {

    case AF_INET:
        // Line 545 below
        ipv4 = (in_addr*)(s.h_addr_list[0]);
        // Line 547 below
        operator=(*ipv4);
        break;
    ...
}
```

And the `hostent` structure:

```
struct hostent {
  char    *h_name;        /* official name of host */
  char    **h_aliases;    /* alias list */
  int     h_addrtype;     /* host address type */
  int     h_length;       /* length of address */
  char    **h_addr_list;  /* list of addresses */
}
```

This squawk is produced on a Mac OS X system, and I recall a recent discussion about this being a bug on Xcode or CFE Dev mailing list (but I can't locate it at the moment).

EDIT: Sean McBride was kind enough to provide a link to the email: [-fcatch-undefined-behavior false positive with readdir()?](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-September/024523.html) I don't agree with the statement that it can be ignored (because its coming from the OS and not the application), especially since it can cause `SIGBUS` errors.

How does one re-align the pointers to clear the Clang issues (`h_addr` is giving me the most trouble)? Can it even be done due to Apple's internal structures depending upon it?

Comment: you are comming from C, right? In C++ is not necessary to specify that an element is a struct: `const struct hostent &s` should be `const hostent &s`

Comment: Also the correct behavior of the assigment operator is to return a reference to the object

Comment: Thanks Manu343726. The code above is existing. There's not telling how long its been there. I'm concerned about the runtime error of unaligned access, and not the language problems.

Comment: You do not have to worry about SIGBUS if it's not actually triggering a SIGBUS, and indeed on x64 and similar CPUs it will not trigger any SIGBUS.  I.e. you can indeed ignore the UBSan runtime warning.  IFF you port to a platform where it could cause SIGBUS, then presumably the related `libc` functions on that platform will not generate `struct hostent` objects with such alignment problems else anything accessing them would always crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you've got a pointer to data which holds the correct values, but at an incorrect offset, you might need to `memcpy` that data. In your case, turn `ipv4` into a stack variable (which will be aligned), and `memcpy` the `s.h_addr_list[0]` to `ipv4`.

Comment: Thanks MSalters. In essence, `s.h_addr` is a `char**`. But I can't dereference it without a bus error. I did try to `memcpy` it out, but I still get an error for unaligned access. So, the `memcpy` removes one unaligned access, but not both. The one that remains appears to be in the deference during the `operator=` call. (And what `operator=` returns is not a battle I'm willing to fight at this time since it does not produce runtime errors ;)

Comment: The alignment error is not from `memcpy`. Doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up doing to fix the two unaligned pointers on Mac OS X 10.8.3. (For completeness, the issues was not present on Ubuntu 13 (x64).

```
void DoSomethingWithHostent(const hostent& he)
{
  // Mac OS X work around 1. Align hostent's h_addr.
  char** ip_addr;
  const void* ptr = (void*)&s.h_addr;
  memcpy(&ip_addr, ptr, sizeof(void*));

  // Mac OS X work around 2. Align in_addr's via memcpy below.
  typedef struct {
    union {
        in_addr ipv4;
        in6_addr ipv6;
    };
  } IN_ADDR_4or6;

  IN_ADDR_4or6 ipv4or6;

  // Back to business logic
  switch (s.h_addrtype) {

  case AF_INET:
    memcpy(&ipv4or6.ipv4, ip_addr, sizeof(ipv4or6.ipv4));
    DoSomethingWithInAddr(ipv4or6.ipv4);
    break;
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@jww's fix works great for C++, however, for C a slight modifications is required: change 'in_addr' to 'struct in_addr'.

I had to port similar code, for comparison this is before (with the unaligned memory access):

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr_list[0]))->s_addr;
```

and after, using memcpy for proper memory alignment:

```
char **ip_addr;
memcpy(&ip_addr, &(host->h_addr_list[0]), sizeof(void *));
memcpy(&address.sin_addr.s_addr, ip_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr));
```